# If an input has a value, specific radio button should be checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if an input (`name="companyname"`) has a value and if so, it should check a radio button (`id="Zakelijk"`). If it does not have any value, it should check the other radio button (`id="Particulier"`).

See my current code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowHideDiv() {
            var chkYes = document.getElementById("Zakelijk");
            var dvPassport1 = document.getElementById("checkzakelijk");
            var dvPassport2 = document.getElementById("checkzakelijk1");
            var dvPassport3 = document.getElementById("checkzakelijk2");
            var display = chkYes.checked ? "block" : "none";
            dvPassport1.style.display = display;
            dvPassport2.style.display = display;
            dvPassport3.style.display = display;
        }
    </script>

    <div class="col-md-12 check-business">
        <div class="form-group form-group-xl">
            <label for="Particulier"><input type="radio" id="Particulier"checked="checked" name="checkzakelijk" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />Particulier</label>
           <label for="Zakelijk"><input type="radio" id="Zakelijk" name="checkzakelijk" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />Bedrijf</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12" id="checkzakelijk" style="display:none;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputCompanyName" class="control-label">{$LANG.clientareacompanyname}</label>
            <input type="text" name="companyname" id="inputCompanyName" value="{$clientcompanyname}"{if in_array('companyname', $uneditablefields)} disabled="disabled"{/if} class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi - you've been provided a number of solutions that should work fine, including multiple jsfiddles showing that they *do* work.   If, as per your comments, these are still not working for you, please create a jsfiddle with your code as a starting point as it might be that there is something else affecting your functionality and this will help rule it out.  See also [mcve], with emphasis on verifiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other ways, but this should get you going:

```
$(function() {
    if (($("#inputCompanyName").val() || "") != "") 
    {
        $("#Zakelijk").prop("checked", true)
    } else {
        $("#Particulier").prop("checked", true)
    }
});
```

This is based on your html where the input name='companyname' also has id 'inputCompanyName' and will clear the other radio because they have the same `name=`

---

**Edit** Working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/76x42os0/4

change input value in the code box (top left) and click run.

Update: Updated the fiddle to the indicated jquery version 3.1.0 and found the newer version of jquery *needs* id= to match #, while before it matched on name=

Comment: Thanks! I tried your code, but that does not seem to work. The radio button is not checked.

Comment: Do you have jquery loaded?  You tagged the question jquery.

Comment: I know, I already load it before `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jque‌​ry.min.js"></script>` But that does not seem to work.

Comment: Did you put this code before your html?  Try adding `$(function() ` (I'll edit the answer)

Comment: That did the trick! Many thanks. Is it also possible to remove the class  style="display:none;" from the id="checkzakelijk", when the "#Zakelijk" is checked?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check it when the input is changed you can do

```
$("input[name='companyname']").change(function(){
      var hasValue = $(this).val() === "";
      $("#Zakelijk").prop("checked", hasValue);
      $("#Particulier").prop("checked", !hasValue);

})
```

you can optimize the code, but this is more readable.

Comment: Thanks! I tried your code, but that does not seem to work. The radio button is not checked.

Comment: @HenkZ you need jQuery.

Comment: I know, I already load it before `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` But that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example of what you're after (albeit without your HTML ids/layout in mind, but you can simply change the IDs within).

```
$("#text-box").on('change', function(){
  if($(this).val() != ""){
    $('#rd1').prop("checked", true)
  }else{
    $('#rd2').prop("checked", true)
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bm18hmLa/3/

It hooks into the changed event, so it would occur every time the text-box value has been changed.

**After thought:**

Changing

```
    $("#text-box").on('change', function(){
```

to

```
    $("#text-box").on('input', function(){
```

makes it a little "nicer" in terms of responsiveness.

https://jsfiddle.net/bm18hmLa/5/

and here's a version with your ID names too.

https://jsfiddle.net/bm18hmLa/6/

Answer (score 0):

In case you need the solution in Javascript

```
if(document.getElementById("inputCompanyName").value !== ""){
   document.getElementById("Zakelijk").checked = true;
   document.getElementById("Particulier").checked = false; 
}
else{
   document.getElementById("Particulier").checked = true;
   document.getElementById("Zakelijk").checked = false;
}
```

Comment: Due to how Radios work you wouldn't need to set one to false when you set one to true.

Comment: Thanks! I tried your code, but that does not seem to work. The radio button is not checked.